# Simple checkout is not working in Authorize .net

Tags: authorize.net

I have created a item in the Authorize.net account and get the code which create the button on website. I have tested it with test mode and order placed successfully. But when I try to make a payment using live mode then at checkout page of Simple checkout it gives me error with following message :

Transaction Declined
The configuration with processor is invalid. Call Merchant Service Provider.

I have called to the Merchant Service Provider and they said that all okay from their side. Some configuration settings are not okay with you integration.

If somebody can help me to fix this issue.

Thanks
Gaurav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to contact Authorize.Net Customer Support to ensure your account is configured properly, call 877-447-3938.